# WebView will not run PIWIK tracking JS

Tags: android, webview, matomo

I created an android app from code that I use with another app of mine. When people use the app, the PIWIK tracking JS will not run. If you visit the website, it tracks fine (The JS tracker is a JS tag on the webpage). If you use the app, it will not track the visit. I have JS enabled, and I copied the code from a app where it was working fine. The only difference in between the two apps is the SDK target versions.

Here is my code below:

```
public class ZestyView extends Activity {

final Activity activity = this;
WebView myWebView;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_zestyview);
    myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Page is loading... Please wait!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    myWebView.loadUrl("https://zestysaver.com/?pk_campaign=App&pk_kwd=Android");
}


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("zestysaver.com")) {
            Log.e("url", Uri.parse(url).getHost());
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, give the default behavior (open in browser)
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
        myWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

}

The tracking code is hosted on an external domain.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the only difference is the API version? And the API version of what? Can you add as much detail as possible to your question?

Comment: I guess I used the wrong term - Sdk version is what I meant. But as far as I can tell, yes that is the only real difference. I am also using the Android Studio to build it as before I was using Eclipse, but that shouldn't make a difference I wouldn't think.

Comment: You might want to specify that in your question. SDK versions, where the tracking code is, how is it loaded, protocols, and what not. As it is, I wouldn't expect an answer.

Comment: @rac Thanks so much for your time.. I finally found the answer. See it below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found my answer. I got to looking through my LogCat and found a line that was not marked as an error:

```
I/X509Util: Failed to validate the certificate chain, error: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Did a little bit of researching to make sure I was right, then ran my website that hosts my analytical software (PIWIK) through [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/), and found the cert chain was not complete. Updated the cert chain on my website, and bam.. started tracking.

Man, I have spent hours on something so silly!